# Removing/ignoring html tags in csv file

Tags: php, csv

been having this problem for a while now, I found many topics about this problem, but they don't really help me.

So Im creating 2 .csv files with this code :

```
<?php 
include 'cnn.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM www_jrpic_lv.web_notikumi_laiki");

//web_notikumi_laiki un web_notikumi izvade

$data = fopen('web_notikumi.csv', 'w');
$data2= fopen('web_notikumi_laiki.csv','w');

//Output Column Headings
fputcsv($data,array('ID Laiks','ID Notikums','Notikuma Laiks','Notikuma beigu laiks'));
fputcsv($data2,array('ID_not','Notikuma apraksts','Notikuma atbildīgais','Notikuma atskats','Baneris','Klase','Nosaukums','Piederība','piev.laiks','red.laiks','ID Tips','Titulbilde','Vieta'));

//Retrieve the data from database
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM web_notikumi_laiki');
$rows2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM web_notikumi');

//Loop through the data to store them inside CSV

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
    fputcsv($data, $row);
    }
while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rows2)){
    fputcsv($data2,$row2);
}
echo '<p>web_notikumi dati ir ievadīti';
echo '<p>web_notikumi_laiki dati ir ievadīti';
fclose($data);
fclose($data2);
exit();
?>
```

Data from table web_notikumi_laiki works well for me, but data in table web_notikumi contains lots of `<p>` tags . And after I use web_notikumi.csv file to fill table in other server it creates new entry after every `<p>` tag so i get ~12 000 entries instead of ~2000. 
My question : Can I remove those tags before I write it to .csv file?
If not what options I have.

Comment: Do you want to remove all tags or just `<p>` tags?

Comment: All of them, but the <p> tags are the ones giving me most headaches, because they make new entries in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags()` to remove any HTML tags from a string. If some HTML elements are allowed, you can whitelist those in the second argument.

```
// for a single column from the query result
fputcsv( $data, strip_tags( $row['column_name'] ) );

// for all columns in the query result
fputcsv( $data, array_map( 'strip_tags', $row ) );
```

See: http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: `$row` is an array so it will need to be `fputcsv( $data, array_map('strip_tags', $row ) );`

Comment: Josh Trii Johnston right, it had to be array but it doesnt seem to work. It creates .csv file but it stays same all the tags are still there.

Comment: Still havent solved this, it did not change at all. I thought this could be usefull when I try to open  this file it says " The file format and extension dont match ... " after I open it anyway  it says " Excel has detected that 'web_notikumi.csv is a SYLK file, but cannot load it. Either the file has errors or it is not a SYLK file format. Click OK to open file in different format '"